# Puppeteer - Cucumber - Use one browser for the tests

Tags: javascript, cucumber, puppeteer, cucumberjs

I'm using Puppeteer and Cucumber for E2E testing on my web app.

On each "steps.js" file for each feature, I have this in the `before` method:

```
Before(async function() {
  this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);
  this.page = await this.browser.newPage();
  await this.page.emulate(GalaxyS5);
  await this.page.goto(URL);
});
```

The problem is when I run it via `cucumber-js` like so: `.\node_modules\.bin\cucumber-js test\e2e\features`, what ends up happening is I have 3 Chromium browsers open up. 2 of those then go to the URL I specify and the last one is just a blank page.

After all browsers are opened, 1 of the 2 of where the URL was redirected too then starts executing the tests.

It seems like every new scenario, a new browser window opens up which is not good because I end up getting a lot of browser windows. Is there a way to specify Puppeteer to only use one browser for the testing or at least on a per feature file basis?

My hierarchy for my project is like this:

```
e2e/
- features/
    - feature1/
      - feature1.feature
      - steps.js (given, when, then, etc.)
    - feature2/
  - world.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding an After:

```
After(async function() {
    // Teardown browser
    if (this.browser) {
       await this.browser.close();
    }
});
```